# Transform an upper triangular matrix into a full matrix C++

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

How would look the code that can transform an upper triangular matrix into a full matrix.
The matrix is in a vector, not in a bidimensional array...

so the array

```
[ 1 2 3 4
  0 5 6 7
  0 0 8 9
  0 0 0 10 ]
```

would become an array like:

```
[ 1 2 3 4
  2 5 6 7
  3 6 8 9
  4 7 9 10 ]
```

could you provide some ideas, I was thinking in applying a kind of module or something...

There is one restriction, **I am not using bidimensional arrays**
I am usng a vector, so is a unidimensional array

Comment: erm, write two nested for loops....? Seriously, it's not even remotely difficult.

Comment: well, I am using a vector, what would be the the conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must understand the fundemtnal nature of a reflected matrix. For any `i`, `j`, the following assertion is true:

```
m[i][j] ≡ m[j][i]
```

So, you need some algorithm to make that true. May I suggest:

```
for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
  for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    m[i][j] = m[j][i];
```

Note the condition of the 2nd loop. By ensuring that `j` is always less than `i`, we restrict our activity to the bottom-left triangle.

Next, you must understand how you have implemented a two-dimensional matrix in a one-dimensional array. It appears that you have established the identity:

```
m[i][j] ≡ v[i*WIDTH+j]
```

Substituting, we have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
  for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    v[i*WIDTH+j] = v[j*WIDTH+i];
```